# How to sum up all numbers entered in prompt

Tags: javascript

```js
var num = prompt("Enter a number");

for (var sum = 0; sum <= num; sum++) {
  sum = sum + 1;
}
document.write(sum);
```

example when I enter 6 in the prompt it will sum 1+2+3+4+5+6 =21. but as of right now i can only print 123456 instead of 21.

Comment: *"as of right now i can only print 123456"* - That's not what the code in the question does...

Comment: Even after fixing the string/number part the logic doesn't seem at all correct. You have both `sum++` and `sum += 1` which won't do what you're intending.

Comment: You're just adding 1 to `sum` each time through the loop, not adding `sum` to a total variable.

Comment: To add to the comments, avoid `document.write()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're using `sum` for the loop and for the answer. That's messing everything up. You can use a variable for the loop and another variable for the sum.

Maybe that works for you.

```js
var num = prompt("Enter a number");
var sum = 0;
for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    sum += i;
}
document.write(sum);
```

Comment: Could you please provide one input that results in a wrong answer?

Comment: @MohitSharma the desired output is correct. It correctly sums up all the number 1 to N, where N is the number entered into the prompt. This is a correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

- Input received by you is a string and that's why it's contacting rather than adding to sum.
- This is the best optimum solution as its time complexity is O(3) times only.
- so, it's fast. rather than with brute force which is o(n);

```js
var num = prompt("Enter a number");

function total(n) {
  return n * (n + 1) / 2;
}
document.write(total(parseInt(num)));
```

Comment: Upvoted for using Pascal's formula. Though passing in the radix to `parseInt` is good practice. Also, your runtime analysis fails to include the runtime for `parseInt` which is not constant time.

Comment: ```total(+num)``` will this one be better? than ```total(parseInt(num))```

Comment: that is a good question; off the top of my head, I am not sure what the runttime performance is for implicit string to number conversion. One would assume that both conversions would be implemented the same under-the-hood, however in Javascript, runtime performance often varies based on the chosen method. Also I was mistaken, it wasn't Pascal who figured out the formula to sum natural numbers, it was supposedly Gauss.

Answer (score -1):

here is some change in your code.
**note**: (+) is used to convert string-number type to number type

```js
var num = prompt("Enter a number");
const sum = Array.from(Array(+num + 1).keys()).reduce((prev, curr) => prev += curr, 0);
document.write(sum);
```

Comment: If you run your code, it does not sum up all the numbers 1 through num.

Comment: @Alan can you give example of what you say

Comment: Run your code. Enter `6`. The answer should be `21`

Comment: @Alan ok got it.

Comment: @Alan i change as per question requirement